# Authorization token Bearer through javascript security

Tags: javascript, jwt

I'm a bit confused about authentication throuhg token.
If I need to call web api authenticated from a web application I need to add the token to all call to the apis: but in this case the token can be easily copied and used to makes authenticated calls.
For example: if I have a .netcore apis backend and web application that use the apis to render informations, the token must be added in javascript calls... or not?

Where I'm wrong? Thank you!

I'm sorry if you find the question very trivial or perhaps stupid but I really can't imagine how a call to a set of api made on the client side can be protected against a token theft. Can you help me clarify? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

JWT’s have an ‘aud’ claim to specify the audience for which they’re valid. Resource servers are supposed to validate that the bearer token came from a member of the audience. So copying the token from ‘good_host’ and trying to use it from ‘bad_host’ should fail.

Answer (score 1):

that's why you should use token authorization only with HTTPS. With HTTPS the channel between client and server is protected and so your token it's not easily stolen.

Comment: Thanks wezzy, ok. But in a web browser I can list the javascript source and I can read the token. It is not so?

Comment: Yes you can see the tokens in the developer tools for example but you should see only yours token. So you cannot see other users token. JWT doesn't expect a single token to be used for more than one user otherwise that will be totally unsecure (and against the usage of JWT)

Answer (score 1):

That's why you should make different tokens with different scopes, so each token can do only the thing i'ts suppoused to do. Maybe a token with a scope for viewing data for normal users so they can make whatever call to the api with that token, but they will be only abled to view whatever you allow them, and other scopes for maybe editing so only admins are abled to make calls to the api to edit things.

More info : https://oauth.net/2/scope/

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, Therefore in a web application developed entirely client side in javscript it is not a good practice to insert administrative activities because there is no way to protect the authorization token. Did I get it right? Thanks

Comment: I mean the answer @VorpalSword gave to you might give you a way to do it with the aud claim so that the token only works from X defined site. That should be safe but I think it's wiser to not develop an entire client side app, always define some endpoints or some data functions on your backend, sensible data and that kind of things.

Comment: Ok, However, for example, google api requires the personal key to use the services. That key is in the clear in the get query and I can copy it and use it for myself 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap

Comment: You should make the restrict the api key as mentioned on the documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key). Go to restrict api key section so you can ensure that the specific key will only work in your specific endpoint. (Also, If you are worried about security check https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#restrict_apikey)